# VueJS - 2 controllers in 1 file

Tags: cakephp, vue.js

How do I make 2 controllers work in 1 view?

For example, this is my view simplified (using CakePHP 3's element page rendering):

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="sub">
        <?= $this->element('main/sub'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the controllers (I use requirejs):

```
require(['jquery', 'vue'], function ($, Vue) {
    return new Vue({
        el: '#main',
        data: {
        },
    });
});

require(['jquery', 'vue'], function ($, Vue) {
    return new Vue({
        el: '#sub',
        data: {
        },
    });
});
```

I keep getting this error and data in `#sub` won't render in DOM.

> vue.js:1141 [Vue warn]: Avoid using reserved keywords in expression:
>   return false;

I'm new to VueJs so I'm unsure if this is a correct setup or not.

Comment: I'm wonder why you want to create nested Vue instance into the main instance ? This is not good approach, you should go with components.

Answer (score 1):

```
requirejs.config({
    BaseUrl: 'js', // App Base URL
    paths: {
        vue: 'lib/vue', // /js/lib/Vue.js Library
        component1: 'components/component1', // /js/components/component1.js
        component2: 'components/component2' // /js/components/component2.js
    }
});

require(['vue', 'component1', 'component2'], function(Vue, C1, C2){

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {},
        components: {
          component1: C1,
          component2: C2
        }
     });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <component1></component1>
  <component2></component2>
</div>
```

Comment: What goes into `/js/components/component1.js`? Is it a normal vue instance?

Comment: @tribungbu components1.js => define(['vue'], function(Vue){ Vue.extend('component1', { your component code }) });